# React native need manual refresh ctrl+s to display data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo, react-native-ui-kitten

```
export default class AchieveScreen extends ValidationComponent{
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        visible: false,
        filter: 1,
        date: new Date(),
        selected: new Date(),
        loaded: false,
        data: [],
        feedbackText:"",
        target:[],
        refreshing:false,
        refreshValue:1
    }
}

handleUpdate = async () => {
    this.setState({ loaded: false })
    await this.getter()
    this.forceUpdate();    
};


GetData = async () => {
    const {date,selected}=this.state
    const data = await GetAchieve()
    if (data.status == 200) {
        this.setState({
            data: data.data,
            target:data.data !== null ? data.data.filter((achieve) => achieve.date.includes(selected)) : null,
            loaded: true,

        })
    }

}

  componentDidMount() {
    this._unsubscribe = this.props.navigation.addListener('focus',() => {
        console.log('ok')
        const UserStatus=this.status()
        if(UserStatus){
            this.GetData()
        }
    });
  }

_onRefresh=async()=> {
    try {
        this.setState({refreshing: true});

        this.setState(({ refreshValue }) => ({
            refreshValue: refreshValue + 1,
          }));
        this.setState({refreshing: false});

    } catch (error) {
        throw error
    }
  }

componentWillUnmount() {
    this._unsubscribe();
}

shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    if(this.state.data != nextState.data){
        console.log('data re')
        return true;
    }
    if(this.state.refreshValue != nextState.refreshValue || this.state.selected != nextState.selected ||  this.state.target != nextState.target ){
        console.log('refreshing value')
        return true;
    }
    return false
  }

sendFeedBack=async()=>{
    const {feedbackText} = this.state
    this.validate({
      feedbackText: {minlength:3, maxlength:4000},
    });
    if(!this.isFieldInError('feedbackText')){
      const request = await feedback(feedbackText)
      if(request.status == 200){
        this.setState({
         feedbackText:"",
         visible:false
        })
      }
    }
  }

flag = (date) => {
    items = this.state.data !== null ? this.state.data.filter((achieve) => achieve.date.includes(date)) : null
    let Professional = false
    let Personal = false
    if (!!items) {
        items.map(item => {
            if (item.flag == 1) { Professional = true } else if (item.flag == 2) { Personal = true }
        })

        if (Professional && Personal) {
            return <>
                <Text> <Icon name="flag-o" size={10} color="#ff6666" /> </Text>
                <Text> <Icon name="star-o" size={10} color="#cc80ff" /> </Text>
            </>

        } else if (Professional) {
            return <Text> <Icon name="flag-o" size={10} color="#ff6666" /> </Text>

        } else if (Personal) {
            return <Text> <Icon name="star-o" size={10} color="#cc80ff" /> </Text>
        }
    }
}
week = () => {
    const { date, selected,loaded } = this.state
    const week = this.state.date.week()
    if(loaded){
    return (
        <>
            {week.map((day, index) => {
                return (
                    selected === week[index].plenaDiem ?
                        <LinearGradient key={index} colors={['#EBDDFD', '#DFDCFF']} start={[0, 1]} end={[1, 0]} style={{ borderRadius: 12 }}>
                            <TouchableOpacity
                                key={index}
                                style={[styles.weekday]}
                                onPress={() => { this.setState({ selected: week[index].plenaDiem }) }}
                                disabled={week[index].enable}
                            >

                                <Text style={styles.name} >{week[index].dies}</Text>
                                <Text style={[styles.num, { color: week[index].color }]} >{week[index].diem}</Text>
                                <View style={styles.flags}>
                                    {this.flag(week[index].plenaDiem)}
                                </View>
                            </TouchableOpacity>
                        </LinearGradient>
                        :
                        <TouchableOpacity
                            key={index}
                            style={[styles.weekday]}
                            onPress={() => {
                                console.log(this.state.target)
                                 this.setState({ 
                                     selected: week[index].plenaDiem,
                                     target:this.state.data !== null ? this.state.data.filter((achieve) => achieve.date.includes(week[index].plenaDiem)) : null,

                                })
                                 }}
                            disabled={week[index].enable}
                        >


                            <Text style={styles.name} >{week[index].dies}</Text>

                            <Text style={[styles.num, { color: week[index].color }]} >
                                {week[index].diem}
                            </Text>

                            <View style={styles.flags}>
                                {this.flag(week[index].plenaDiem)}
                            </View>

                        </TouchableOpacity>

                )
            
            })
        }
            
            
        </>
    )
    }
}



render() {
    const { data, date, visible, selected, filter, loaded,feedbackText,refreshing,target } = this.state
    // let render = data !== null ? data.filter((achieve) => achieve.date.includes(selected)) : null
    // if (filter !== 3 && render !== null) {
    //     render = render.filter((item) => item.flag == filter)
    // }
     
    return (
    
        <>


            <View style={styles.header}  >
                <View style={styles.top}>
                    <View style={styles.icon}>

                        <Image source={require('../../assets/header/CalendarIcon.png')} />
                        <Text style={styles.day}>{date.day()}</Text>

                    </View>

                    <View style={styles.items}><Image source={require('../../assets/header/medalLogo.png')} /></View>
                    <View style={styles.items}><IconButton icon='question' style={styles.question} color={"#000"} size={16} onPress={() => this.setState({ visible: true })} /></View>

                </View>

                <Modal
                    visible={visible}
                    backdropStyle={styles.backdrop}
                    onBackdropPress={() => this.setState({ visible: false })}>
                    <Card disabled={true} style={{backgroundColor:"#FFF",width:wp('90%'),borderRadius:10}}>
                       <Input
                        name='feedbackText'
                        value={feedbackText}
                        style={styles.feedbackText}
                        multiline={true}
                        maxLength={4000}
                        placeholder="tell us about you expermenit"
                        onChangeText={(text) => { this.setState({ 
                            feedbackText: text,
                         }) }}
                        />   
                        <Button
                        disabled={feedbackText.length<3?true:false}
                        onPress={() => {this.sendFeedBack()}}>
                                subimt
                        </Button>

                    </Card>
                    
                    <View style={[styles.close]}>
                        <AntDesign name={"closecircleo"} color="#000" onPress={() => this.setState({ visible: false })} size={25} />
                    </View>
                </Modal>
                <ScrollView
                    contentContainerStyle={styles.scrollView}
                    refreshControl={
                    <RefreshControl
                        refreshing={refreshing}
                        onRefresh={this._onRefresh.bind(this)}
                    />
                    }
                >

                <View style={styles.month}>
                    <Text style={styles.monthName}>{date.monthName()}</Text>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.week}>
                    {loaded ? this.week() : <LoadingScreen/>}
                </View>
                </ScrollView>

            </View>

            <View style={styles.container}  >
                <View style={styles.achieve}>
                    <View>
                        {/* <SwitchSelector
                            options={options}
                            initial={0}
                            style={styles.switch}
                            buttonColor={"#fff"}
                            textColor={"#AB9CB3"}
                            selectedColor={"#000"}
                            buttonMargin={3}
                            imageStyle={styles.switchicon}
                            backgroundColor={"#F0F1F8"}
                            onPress={value => this.setState({ filter: value })}
                        /> */}
                    </View>
                    <View style={styles.count}>
                        <Text style={styles.countText}>you have achieved {target !== null ? target.length : null}</Text>
                    </View>
                </View>

                <View style={styles.cards}>
                    <Cards type={true} data={target} storage={data} handle={this.handleUpdate} />
                </View>


            </View>
        </>
    )
}
```

}
this is calendar component when run it no thing to display but data can be in console log. i can show data there, I need to hit Ctrl+s to refresh expo 'fast refresh' to show data in simulator

I have load Logic in render section but issue is still need fix

any suggestions?

[this screen before hit Ctrl+s data is already in state but not rendering "first run"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bjYSn.jpg)

[here after hit Ctrl+s to refresh screen to show data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/898uw.jpg)